# bash --version. Where this info are stored?

Tags: bash, macos, environment-variables

In which file are stored the info about the command 
    `bash --version`
?
I've tried in some directories like /bin or /var, /etc, but without results...

I need both for Linux and MAC OS x. Thanks!

Comment: Probably hard coded into the executable. Why wouldnt it be?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what exactly did you try in those directories?

Comment: i'm searching for some variables related to the /bin/bash executable... i'm a almost-newbie :D

Comment: @Alex_DeLarge You probably should look in the `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any reason to believe that it is not hard-coded in the `bash`-executable itself?

To find out which `bash` is used, run

```
which bash
```

For me, it gives `/bin/bash`. Now, to see whether the executable has any string-like byte sequences in it that contain the substring `"version"`, run

```
strings /bin/bash | grep version
```

On this machine, it gives:

```
shell_version_string
build_version
sccs_version
rl_library_version
rl_do_lowercase_version
show_shell_version
rl_readline_version
dist_version
GNU bash, version %s-(%s)
GNU bash, version %s (%s)
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
@(#)Bash version 4.3.48(1) release GNU
display-shell-version
      -l    do not print tilde-prefixed versions of directories relative
    HOSTTYPE    The type of CPU this version of Bash is running under.
    OSTYPE  The version of Unix this version of Bash is running on.
    version, type `enable -n test'.
do-lowercase-version
.gnu.version
.gnu.version_r
```

Thus, `"Bash version 4.3.48"` is hard-coded in the executable as an ordinary string.

Comment: clear, thanks. What if i want to edit a line?
E.g., in command bash --version i get 
GNU bash, versione 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

and i want to print the world "copyleft" instead of "copyright"

Comment: Why do you care about the wording? If it mattered, I'm pretty sure the maintainers would make the change in the source code. You can always edit the source code and recompile yourself.

Comment: @Alex_DeLarge In the executable itself? I guess you could use some hex-editors for  that, or [use hexdump in combination with `sed`](http://everydaywithlinux.blogspot.de/2012/11/patch-strings-in-binary-files-with-sed.html). I'm not a lawyer, I'm not sure whether it's a good idea to edit someone else's copyright notices. Why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: @Alex_DeLarge. Do you plan to distribute said executable to anyone else?

Comment: @Alex_DeLarge. You'd probably learn a lot more by recompiling bash from source.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The reverse direction is also very fun, and *very* different from the "source code -> compile -> executable" direction. If you play through the binary bomb once, you won't forget the `strings` utility so fast, which in turn means that you don't have to google your way through strange results for query "man strings" to look up what it does ;)

Comment: so, is there a way to edit a few words of a binary executable without finding and editing the source code and than compile it?

Comment: @Alex_DeLarge Third comment: hex-editors, hexdump, sed, linked article. Actually, it looks as if you could even edit it with vim.

Comment: @Alex_DeLarge, you need to be careful about not changing the offsets -- you can modify strings, but only if you keep them the same length, or *sometimes* if you make them shorter and add NULs as padding. Otherwise you can disassemble, modify and reassemble... which is certainly educational as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
strings $(which bash) | grep "Bash version"
```

Output (e.g.):

```
@(#)Bash version 4.3.48(1) release GNU
```

Comment: Does strings extract only the portions of a binary file that appear to be valid Unicode?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: GNU strings prints the printable character sequences that are at least 4 characters long and are followed by an unprintable character. Option `--encoding=encoding` might help with Unicode UTF-16/UCS-2 encodings.

Comment: Thanks for enabling my laziness :) I'd never seen  this program before but was too lazy to search.

Comment: I'd have to Google it on an android. Not sure what I'd get for that particular combination of words :)